# Can't deploy transaction to fabric-core

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm using Vagrant enviroment. I managed to start peer, my chaincode was successfully registered, but when I try to deploy i'm getting the following

> vagrant@hyperledger-devenv:v0.2.1-82e72f4:~$
>   CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=172.17.0.2:7051 peer chaincode deploy -n mytcc -c
>   '{"Args": ["init", "a","100", "b", "200"]}' - p
>   github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02
>   Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = 12 desc = unknown
>   service protos.Endorser

I'm using the following docker-compose.yml file, to launch fabric-peer

```
   vp0:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
  environment:
    - CORE_PEER_ID=vp0
    - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
    - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://172.17.0.1:2375
    - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev
```

The fllowing is the command for registering my transaction, and it succeds

```
CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mytcc CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=172.17.0.2:7051 ./chaincode_example02
```

But then, the following command fails

```
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=172.17.0.2:7051 peer chaincode deploy -n mytcc -c '{"Args": ["init", "a","100", "b", "200"]}' 
-p github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02
```

What is protos.Endorser? Thank you!

Comment: This question/issue was raised when the project was under (hyper_-active development in the transition from v0.6 to 1.0 architecture and likely transient. Apologies for not being attentive to SO.